# How is quite used here?

Tags: nouns, quantifiers

"it was ... interesting to see these (1) quite deprived areas (1) erm  (.)"

Is quite here being used as an quantifier and is the noun "areas" countable in this context? It sounds to me like 'quite' is also used as a filler but I'm not sure. For example, when girls colloquially add unecessary "like" and "really" in their phatic talk.

Comment: The ellipses represent the pause in speech, correct? Is this something you heard or read? The numbers in brackets is your way to highlight or emphasise  the word ***quite***, correct?

Comment: Could you please use one * on either side of the word for *italics*, or two ** to **embolden** a word. Thanks :)

Comment: @Mari-Lou The ellipsis represents omission of a word (contraction/elision). The number in brackets represents the seconds of the pause (3) and the (.) is a micropause. I can't add any italics or bold because I posted this on my phone.

Comment: Also this is a quote from a format of a spoken transcript. I didn't just write it down.

Comment: So this quote is from a recorded piece of audio. Could you include its link, please? Please cite your source. P.S. You should say **in** your question what those marks mean, I had no idea until you explained. Phones do have asterisks, you can use them for italics and bold, or you can use the editing tools that is positioned above the question box when you reopen it. Click the link: https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/426043/edit PPS it is customary to enclose ellipsis in square brackets [...] to show it is not a pause in speech

Comment: @Mari-Lou A I can't link the source it's from my A-level English Language and Literature Anthology, it's not available ONLINE for copyright reasons. I can put what the symbols mean but I have already explained this. I will do that later. This question has been answered.